# Time traveled assuming instant acceleration/decelaration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I am working on sort of a motion planning algorithm where I need to estimate the time it takes to travel along a certain path of points (straight lines between consecutive points, i.e I am assuming motion to be on one dimension between consecutive points).

My input is a set of points: 
(x1, y1), 
(x2, y2, [list of allowed velocities at p2]), 
(x3, y3, [list of allowed velocities at p3]), 
(x4, y4, [list of allowed velocities at p4]), 
..., 
(x9, y9,),

So I start at rest at point1 and stop at point9 but when I reach point pi I need to have velocity from the list for that point (I know this is not very realistic to have a discrete number of allowable velocities but the reason for that is to reduce computational complexity. I could relax lists into ranges if that makes it easier). In addition to the above, I am given a maximum acceleration/deceleration constant A as well as a maximum velocity V which is greater than anything in the lists.

The end goal is to calculate the minimum time required to travel along the path (without violating constraints). I know how to calculate this time if the distances between every two points are long enough:

- For every segment (assuming I already know the velocity at the start of the segment, say v_init), find the time delta_t1 it takes to accelerate to V + time delta_t3 it takes to decelerate from V to the max allowed velocity of the next point + time delta_t2 it takes to travel the remaining distance not covered by those acc/decc periods.
- delta_t1 = (V - v_init) / A;
- delta_t3 = (V - v_final) / A;
- delta_d1 = displacement(delta_t1, v_init, A);
- delta_d3 = displacement(delta_t3, v_final, A);
- delta_d2 = distance - (delta_d1 + delta_d3);
- delta_t2 = delta_d2 / V;

Now the problem is that delta_d2 could be negative, i.e. I don't have enough distance to reach the maximum velocity. In which case, I need to adjust the maximum velocity but that's where I am stuck :) 
Am I looking at this the right way? (Bonus: Can this be generalized in the case of adjustable acceleration, i.e. when we also have jerk).

I am aware that this is very closely related to T-Motion and S-Motion profiles (Trapezoidal and Sinusoidal), but my hope is that I don't need the full complexity of those profiles to just get a "rough" time estimate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Definitely not a programming question, and it's a thin line between physics and maths :) The question is really about how to compute velocities so that constraints are not violated. Not sure if anyone without a physics background can answer.

Comment: Is this really a physics problem?  It seems more like programming or mathematics to me.  Other SE sites may be able to provide better answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the speed of the vehicle as it passes a particular point must be one of the values in a list.  The list is different for each point.  The overall time is minimized by choosing the maximum speeds possible at each "checkpoint", subject to the constraints.

I think what you might be missing is that, if the starting speed on a section of road is u and the finishing speed at the end is v then
$v^2 = u^2+2As$
where A is the maximum acceleration/deceleration and s is the length of the section.

Work your way through the list of points in order, calculating the maximum speed $v_{max}$ which you could reach at the end of the current section of road, using the above equation.  Then select the highest allowed value $v$ from the list which is less than $v_{max}$.  The time for that section is t where
$s = \frac12(u+v)t$
$t = \frac{2s}{u+v}$.

If the highest speed in the list is below $u$, then you will have to decelerate.  In this case the lowest speed $v_{min}$ which you could reach is now given by replacing $A$ with $-A$ in the equation for $v^2$.  Again you should select the highest speed in the list, but this time from those which are above $v_{min}$.  If there are no speeds available above $v_{min}$ then you will have to "backtrack".

This procedure is not guaranteed to give you the quickest time, but in most cases it will be close. Note that there is no need to check that the speed is below the limit V because the maximum speeds occur at the checkpoints and are restricted to those on the list, which must be less than V.

Comment: Hey Sammy, thank you for the answer. I have a question though as I don't think I fully understand your procedure. If we assume only three points where the middle point allows any velocity up the max, wouldn't this procedure be highly overestimating the time?

Comment: @amer : Sorry I don't see what you mean.  Can you provide an example with numbers to show that the procedure overestimates the time?